Azure function v2 (python) to chunk data in a for loop does not output to blob storage
Im trying to write a simple for loop that cut's a list into chunks within an Azure function v2 (python) and outputs these blobs to csvs.
import logging
import azure.functions as func


app = func.FunctionApp()

@app.blob_trigger(arg_name="myblob", path="old/{name}",connection="Storage") 
@app.blob_output(arg_name="outputblob", path="new/{name}",connection="Storage") 
def BlobTrigger(myblob: func.InputStream,outputblob: func.Out[str]):
    results = random.sample(range(1, 500), 7)
    step = 10
    for i in range(0, len(results), step): 
        x = i 
        results_chunked = results[x:x+step]
        df = pd.DataFrame(results_chunked)
        filename = '/tmp/'+ str(i) +'.csv'
        output_csv = df.to_csv(filename,index = False)
        outputblob.set(output_csv)

Blob function was executed successfully

However the chuncked data (output_csv) is not being received in path="new/{name}" any assistance on this ?

You need to use sdk in order to pass the specific file name. If you will remove the filename then you will get the output

Can you specify your requirement as in how many files you expect to be created? Only one file is getting created by using your code @Jimmy3421

@IkhtesamAfrin which sdk is that ? If I remove the filename the function will not work as the file will be overwritten?

Yes the function will work and write the output in the same file name but in the new container

@IkhtesamAfrin will this not overwrite the original file in the new container if they have the same name ?

AFAIK, It is not yet feasible in the case of output binding to pass the blob name dynamically. You can use the Blob Storage SDK for the same.
I am able to get the output by using the below code.
import azure.functions as func
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient
import random
import pandas as pd
import os

app = func.FunctionApp()

def upload_blob(connection_string, container_name, blob_name, data):
    blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connection_string)
    container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client(container_name)
    blob_client = container_client.get_blob_client(blob_name)
    blob_client.upload_blob(data)

@app.blob_trigger(arg_name="myblob", path="old/{name}", connection="afrinstore01_STORAGE")
def blob_trigger(myblob: func.InputStream):
    connection_string = os.environ["afrinstore01_STORAGE"]
    results = random.sample(range(1, 500), 7)
    step = 3
    for i in range(0, len(results), step): 
        results_chunked = results[i:i+step]
        df = pd.DataFrame(results_chunked, columns=["Values"])
        filename = '/tmp/'+ str(i) +'.csv'
        df.to_csv(filename, index=False)
        with open(filename, "rb") as data:
            upload_blob(connection_string, "new", f"{i}.csv", data.read())
        os.remove(filename)

requirements.txt-
azure-functions
pandas
azure-storage-blob

Output-


How do I add the blob name into the file name? the following does not work
filename = '/tmp/'+ myblob.name +'.csv'

You need to only pass the blob name because myblob.name returns container/blob.extension. That's the reason you are facing issue

For some reason I couldn't get it to work? Secondly how would I put the .csv directly in the new folder rather than /tmp/? Thanks

While uploading the blob, you need to upload in this way

this is a manual way I mean through your code snippet above?

@Jimmy3421 Initially upload any test blob to a new folder as you can't create a blank folder. Once the folder is created in the container, you can use the folder name in the place of /tmp/ in your code

Thanks, will it go into the function like this upload_blob("xxx", "new/outputfolder", filename, data.read())
"new/ouputfolder" rather than "new"  ?

I believe it will be "new" as upload_blob function's second arguments expects container name
